Discussions guideline on the sidebar is mingled
The Discussions guideline on the right sidebar is not aligned vertically and extends beyond to the right when visiting a discussion post. This is most probably related to these recent changes. See the Screenshot:

It is supposed to look like this:

I was able to reproduce this with and without user scripts, on Windows, MacOS, and Android, using Edge, Chrome, Firefox, and Brave browsers.

A fix is on it's way today/very soon.

Mingled? Do you mean "mangled"?

@PM2Ring no, it's mixed up and has moved around, it is not "disfigured".

The issue has now been fixed. We've recently made a change to the headers in the right sidebar widgets in Stacks. Even though those headers were already using the Stacks component, most of them had a variety of additional custom atomic classes. The new component helps consolidate and remove the need for so many custom classes but also meant that we needed to manually go through each page that uses this header and clean up the code. This page slipped through, I personally should have seen and caught this issue before it went live, that was a miss on my part. Thanks for taking the time to report it.

Thank you. On another note, why do we need <div class="js-sidebar-zone" style="min-height: 300px;"> on the SO homepage? The minimum height results in an empty space between widgets. I actually appreciate the class/div as I can use it for my userscript: https://stackapps.com/questions/10634/hide-the-newly-introduced-homepage-widgets/10635#10635 but you should get rid of the minimum height probably. I will post something if found the time, but thought I should let you know sooner. p.s. it works as intended on other sites.

The new designs for the headers were released with the new homepage when that launch happened as custom classes. We took those design updates and have now implemented in Stacks (and the rest of the site). We decided not to touch the homepage as part of our site wide update/cleanup since there's a team working on fixes for that page specifically right now. The homepage likely needs some of it's own cleanup that will come separately. But I'll share your note specifically with that team.
